# Android device volume control from ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

is there any volume control plugin for ionic 3?

I can't find anything but I really need it. The only possibility I found was ionic native media plugin but you can only set volume for audio files (like mp3).

Comment: Hi, I made that plugin for internal issue. Stay in contact i will share some idea with you